# Using Require.js with pluggable modules

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I would like to use Require.js to create pluggable modules. My intention of pluggable modules is that I can have an interface such as "Module1 should have `method1(x,y)` and `method2(a,b)`".

Then, on some configuration I can load a different Require.js module with that interface.

So for example, if running the code in a staging env I would use `'app/stage/mymodule'` and if running in production I would use `'app/prod/mymodule'` - where both adhere to the given interface, though both mapped to the variable.

Example:

Env = Staging: `define(['app/stage/mymodule'], function(mod1) { ... });`

Env = Production: `define(['app/prod/mymodule'], function(mod1) { ... });`

Now, I understand that a true interface can't be achieved in JS - that is fine. I'm just interested in the second part - using modules based on some initial configuration passed through `require.config` that will affect the whole app.

Comment: require.config is great. My question is how would that allow to load different modules - while the hosting module will have the same interface. As I've written - I would like to load different modules, with different behaviour - but same interface, when using different environments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
define(function (require, exports, module) {
    // module.config returns only that section of the configuration that
    // pertains to **this** module; not the whole configuraiton.
    var config = module.config();
    var env = config.env;
    // Compute the dependency...
    var env_to_module_map = {
        stage: 'app/stage/mymodule',
        production: 'app/prod/mymodule'
    };
    var dep = env_to_module_map[env];

    if (!dep)
        // configuration error
        throw new Error("..."); // Whatever appropriate.

    require([dep], function (mod) {
        mod.method1(1, 2);
    });
});
```

Assuming the module above is called `main`, your RequireJS config would have something like:

```
require.config({
    ....,
    config: {
        main: {
            env: "stage" // Or "production".
        }
    }
});
```

Note that this complicates optimizing a little bit because `r.js` is unable to follow dependencies that are computed at run time. You *will* have to explicitly list one or both modules (`'app/stage/mymodule'` and `'app/prod/mymodule'`) in the build configuration you give to `r.js`, otherwise neither will be included.

This method is the one that allows maximum flexibility at run time. You can create a bundle that contains everything needed and let whoever is responsible decide when they install the bundle whatever value of `env` they want to use, and the right module will be loaded.

Comment: Thank you very much! One Question - If I understood right, in each module that needs this dynamic binding - I would have to include all the "intro" code to use the configuration. Right? Nothing automatic that will do this for me?

Comment: I guess I could create some dynamic binding helper module to do this for me... right?

Comment: There's no automatic feature of RequireJS that would replace the code that computes the dependency from the configuration you give. The code that computes `dep` from `env` could be put into a utility module that you load. This would save you a few lines and is very easy to do. It may be possible to save more lines but it really depends on the specifics of your project, whether you are okay working with promises, etc.